# Invoking a perl script from JQuery code

Tags: jquery, perl

I am trying to run the script `getNewFollowing.pl` from jquery, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cross").livequery("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("getNewFollowing.pl, 
        function(data){
         $('#follow_name1').text(data.userName);
           $('#follow_email1').text(data.userEmail);                    
     });

  });
});
```

When I click the link with `ID="cross"`, it should call a perl file which returns userName and userEmail.

This code is not invoking the perl script.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's it *meant* to be doing? What HTML should it act upon?

Comment: Missing ending bracket of $.post();

Comment: Missing quote after getNewFollowing.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a quote (") after "getNewFollowing.pl".

```
$(function(){
    $("#cross").livequery("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post("getNewFollowing.pl", {}, function(data){
           $('#follow_name1').text(data.userName);
           $('#follow_email1').text(data.userEmail);                    
       });
    });
});
```

Note that there are a lot of helpful tools (for all major browsers) out there that help you narrow problems like this down faster. Information coming from these tools is also valued here on StackOverflow when you ask your question.

Comment: Hi J.P., Thanks for response. Its working now. I want to know, is there really need for $(function(){ (first line) and });
(last line)

Comment: @SapnaAgrawal: First, the `$(function() { } );` is a shortened version of your `$(document).ready(function() { } );`. These two statements are identical. Second, what you're doing with those statements is that you are executing the supplied function when the DOM is loaded. If this is not required for your JavaScript code (e.g. your `<script>` tag is at the bottom of your page meaning the DOM has already been built), then you can omit it. Either way, it's not harmful to leave it in.

Answer (score 1):

There can be any number of reasons why the script does not run which depends on what web server you are using and its configuration.

Best thing to learn/do is:

1. Use a JavaScript debugger like Chrome developer tools if you are using chrome or firebug if you are using Firefox.
2. Set the break point on the line (script section of the tool), then see whats happening. This will help you in long run.

http://getfirebug.com/javascript/

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview